# kustomize build Error: no matches for Id SecretProviderClass.v1.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/azure-kvname-user-msi

Tags: kustomize

I am trying to run

```
kustomize build .\services\showcase\overlays\dev\
```

the content of the services\showcase\base\secretclass.yaml  is the following

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname-user-msi
  namespace: showcase
spec:
  provider: azure
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: connection-string
      type: kubernetes.io/tls
      data:
        - objectName: connection-str
          key: connectionstr
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"
    useVMManagedIdentity: "true" # Set to true for using managed identity
    userAssignedIdentityID: 674a3fcb-2456-4aba-aaa9-xxxxxx # Set the clientID of the user-assigned managed identity to use
    keyvaultName: kv-arm-shared-dev-f-02 # Set to the name of your key vault
    cloudName: "" # [OPTIONAL for Azure] if not provided, the Azure environment defaults to AzurePublicCloud
    objects: |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: ConnectionStrings-showcase
          objectAlias: connection-str
          objectType: secret              # object types: secret, key, or cert
          objectVersion: ""               # [OPTIONAL] object versions, default to latest if empty
    tenantId: de33eaa6-4346-40a0-882c-xxxxxxxxx # The tenant ID of the key vault
```

the kustomization.yaml file content is

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../../base

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - deployment.yaml
  - secretclass.yaml
```

and secretclass.yaml under .\services\showcase\overlays\dev\ is identical to the base.
I am getting the following error

```
kustomize build .\services\showcase\overlays\dev\
Error: no matches for Id SecretProviderClass.v1.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/azure-kvname-user-msi.showcase; failed to find unique target for patch SecretProviderClass.v1.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/azure-kvname-user-msi.showcase
```